# Overriding QPaintEvents in PyQt

Tags: qt, qt4, pyqt, pyqt4, qtgui

I'm trying to create a TextEdit widget that will have a delimiter line. As a start, I've created a `MyTextEdit` class (as a subclass of a `QTextEdit`) and overridden its `paintEvent()` method:

```
import sys
from PyQt4.QtGui import QApplication, QTextEdit, QPainter

class MyTextEdit(QTextEdit):
    """A TextEdit widget derived from QTextEdit and implementing its
       own paintEvent"""

    def paintEvent(self, event):
        painter = QPainter(self)
        painter.drawLine(0, 10, 10, 10)
        QTextEdit.paintEvent(self, event)

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
textEdit = MyTextEdit()
textEdit.show()

sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Trying to execute this code, I get **lots** of the following errors:

```
QPainter::begin: Widget painting can only begin as a result of a paintEvent
QPainter::begin: Widget painting can only begin as a result of a paintEvent
...
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If a widget has a [viewport](http://doc-snapshot.qt-project.org/4.8/qabstractscrollarea.html#viewport), you have to pass that to the `QPainter` constructor:

```
painter = QPainter(self.viewport())
```

Comment: interesting, yea, I couldn't figure out why that wasn't working.  That viewport always screws me up.  Thanks!